# Waiting for file to download on selenium grid

Tags: selenium, webdriver, selenium-grid

I have a test using Webdriver and C# which downloads a file from a website.
When running this test on my local machine it works fine but when I try to run it on Selenium grid it Looks for the file I'm downloading on the hub and not on the node.

Is the anyway of accessing the node file structure to monitor when the file is downloaded.

Sorry if this is unclear.

Thanks
Aidan

Comment: How are you locating the file? I'm using (user directory path variable + "Downloads") to locate the file which won't work for a node or hub.

Answer (score 0):

It seems, there is no such possibility.. I have also tried to find such functionality, but failed.
But, one way to check it still exists - "upload downloaded". Of course it is workaround and not always you have such function as upload.

Anyway, you may:

1. download test data
2. delete test data from page
3. upload test data on page again
4. check it was really appeared

It is quite dirty way, but on other hand it allows you to test not only download function, but also upload function.